# Recursively computing x^-n

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I am fairly new to programming and am trying to come up with a way to recursively compute x^-n. (An explanation behind the math and the difference between recursively computing x^n would be appreciated):

```
double power(double x, int n)
{
    if (n == 0) 
        return 1.0;

    return x * power(x, n - 1)
}
```

Comment: Just use x^-n = (1/x)^n

Comment: Simply remember that `x^(-n) = 1 / (x^n)`

Comment: `x^-n` can be recast as `1/(x)^n` which will work with your existing function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x<sup>-n</sup> is mathematically equal to 1/x<sup>n</sup>, so you could adapt the classic recursive calculation of x<sup>n</sup> to handle it too:

```
double power (double x, int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        return 1.0 / power(x, -1 * n);
    }
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1.0;
    }
    return x * power (x, n - 1);
}
```

Comment: Such algorithm has one reduntant comparision that goes through each recursive call. It possible to use wrapper function to check sign of n and then call recursive helper function.

Comment: @OrestHera Or just put the most common case  `if (n > 0) ...`  as the first comparison.

Comment: Why did you choose `-1 * n` as opposed to `-n`?

Comment: @pjs Just seemed more explicit, no real reason

Comment: And if you wanna be a bit fancy (and faster for large n), you use repeated squaring instead of recursive multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

`x^-n` is equivalent to `1/(x^n)`. Just have a statement like `double result = 1.0/power(x,n);` in your calling method

Answer (score 0):

x^-n is actually 1/(x^n)

So, your function can be rewritten as

```
double power_1(double x, unsigned int n)
{
    if (n == 0) 
        return 1.0;

    return power_1(x, n - 1) / x;
}
```

Note that your algorithm is not tail recursive. For the [tail call optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) it is useful to write something like that:

```
double power_1(double x, unsigned int n, double res = 1.0)
{
    if (n == 0) 
        return res;

    return power_1(x, n - 1, res / x);
}
```

The last `res` parameter is an accumulator for the result. It should be 1.0 for external usage. The result is transfered through all recursive calls as a function argument. In C where default function argumenst are not supported it can be called as `power_1(x, n, 1.0)` or in C++ as `power_1(x, n)`.

Answer (score 0):

The process is fairly simple. I've written this in VB.NET since it's like English, a bit easy to understand.

```
Function I(ByVal x As Double, ByVal n As Integer) As Double
    If n = 0 Then
        Return 1
    End If
    Return 1 / x * I(x, n - 1)
End Function
```

Whenever writing a function in recursion it is essential to identify the base cases. For instance, what can the problem be broken down into?

Here the base case is for n = 0 which is simply 1.

Then is the recurrent step that would construct the problem out of these base steps.

Answer (score 0):

This basically keeps getting unknowns until it gets to the n == 0 case. Once it gets there, it returns 1, which means it can then figure out what n == 1 case should return. You can think of it as waiting to return it's x * power(x, n - 1), until one of the x * power(x, n - 1) lines returns something, which happens when n == 0. From there it can figure out what the x ==1 case is, and so on until it finally figures out the final answer and returns to your main code.

here with graphics from 3:

what's the case for x=3?
   -need to get x=2 for that

```
  ok, what's the case for x=2?
     -need to get x=1 for that

        ok, what's the case for x=1?
          -need to get x=0 for that

             ok, what's the case for x=0?
                -the answer is one1

        ok, then my answer is a bunch of stuff using case x=0's answer (1)

    ok, then my answer is a bunch of stuff using case x=1's answer which uses x=0's answer (1)

  ok, then my answer is a bunch of stuff using case=2's answer which uses x=1's answer, which uses x=1's answer (1)
```

Answer (score -1):

As everybody has said, x^-n is equal to 1/x^n. Therefore, this could be an answer:

```
function power(double x, int n) {
   if (n == 0) 
      return 1.0;

   return 1/ x*power(x, n + 1)
}
```